# How to make a 3d dataset from bunch of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset of 1002 of time steps and in each time step I have observed 11 features and it has been stored in the tuples like below:

```
      timestep  F1        F2   F3   F4     F5   ...  F10       F11  
0         0.0   1.0      1.0  1.0  1.0  0.010568  0.505733  0.000000   
1         0.0   1.0      1.0  1.0  1.0  0.011527  0.505982  0.000689   
2         0.0   1.0      1.0  1.0  1.0  0.012487  0.506870  0.001379   
3         0.0   1.0      1.0  1.0  1.0  0.013446  0.506084  0.002068   
5         0.0   1.0      1.0  1.0  1.0  0.015365  0.507045  0.003447 
...
```

I want to store them concatenated based on my time steps and in the end, I would like to have a 3D dataset of (TimeSteps, observation, features) like the picture below.
[image]

The simple code that I have written is below and it throws the error: `tuple indices must be integers or slices, not str`

```
importing libraried

df = pd.read_csv('BETA10.csv', sep="\s+", header=None)
df.columns = ['F1','F2','F3','F4','F5','F6','F7','F8','F9','F10']
dataset = df.values
dataset = df.astype('float32')
## To add Timestep
dataset['timestep'] = np.nan
dataset['diff'] = np.nan
dataset['diff'] = dataset['Beta'].diff()
dataset['timestep'][0] = 0
idx_newts = dataset[dataset['diff']!=0].index
dataset.loc[dataset.index.isin(idx_newts),'timestep'] = np.arange(len(idx_newts))
dataset['timestep'].ffill(inplace=True)
del dataset['diff']

## To separate data between train and test
train_dataset = dataset.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=0)
test_dataset = dataset.drop(train_dataset.index)
## To normalize data
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
scaler.fit(train_dataset[columns_to_normalize])

train_dataset[columns_to_normalize] = scaler.transform(train_dataset[columns_to_normalize])
test_dataset[columns_to_normalize] = scaler.transform(test_dataset[columns_to_normalize])
## To group by time step
id_train ,df_train_list = [],[]

for idx, df in enumerate(train_dataset.groupby("timestep")):
    id_train.append(idx)
    df_train_list.append(df)
id_test ,df_test_list = [],[]

for idx, df in enumerate(test_dataset.groupby("timestep")):
    id_test.append(idx)
    df_test_list.append(df)
 
## TO reshape into a 3-D datset 

length = []
time_step = []
for tup in df_train_list:
    for item in tup:
        df_train_array = np.array(df_train_list[0][item])
    length.append(df_train_array)
```

Comment: check type of you data in each step

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi the type in each time step is still pandas dataframe `class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'`

Comment: you try add or access come element with string instead of integer value

Comment: post some reproducible example

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi how to make a 3d data set using from tuples,  mean using from an element of tuples

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi I made it more clear, if you could, take a look at that. Thanks

Comment: too much post data inside `df_train_list`